# Google Sheets API v4 for Flutter/Dart

Tags: dart, google-sheets-api, flutter, google-apis-explorer

Will there be Google Sheets API v4 support for [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/)/[Flutter](https://flutter.io/), if yes when is it coming? It already has support for many languages but Dart/Flutter is not listed in their [guides](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[googleapis package](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) can be used in Flutter and supports Sheets v4

See also this [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898)

Comment: Thanks Gunter. Pity that not many examples for dartlang google apis, and no example for google sheets api.

Comment: Yup, but examples from other languages shouldn't be too hard to convert. If you're stuck just post a question.

Answer (score 5):

I created a project, enabled the sheets API for it, then created a 'robot-style' service account, and download the key as JSON. I then created a Google Sheet, and made it publicly accessible, noting its key.

This code connects, and updates an existing sheet by appending a new line of data. No error handling, but some print() statements to help visualise the flow.

```
// Key for service account copied from downloaded file for demo purposes ;-)
final _key = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": //etc
  // ...
  // ...
};

print('getting oauth');
auth
    .obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(
        auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(_key),
        scopes,
        http.Client())
    .then((auth.AccessCredentials cred) {
  print('got oauth');

  auth.AuthClient client = auth.authenticatedClient(http.Client(), cred);
  SheetsApi api = new SheetsApi(client);
  ValueRange vr = new ValueRange.fromJson({
    "values": [
      [ // fields A - J
        "15/02/2019", "via API 3", "5", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"
      ]
    ]
  });
  print('about to append');
  api.spreadsheets.values
      .append(vr, '1cl...spreadsheet_key...W5E', 'A:J',
          valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED')
      .then((AppendValuesResponse r) {
    print('append completed.');
    client.close();
  });
  print('called append()');
});
print('ended?');
```

}

Comment: What the scope should be? Where can I find the related information?

Comment: Have a look at the OAuth2 documentation for the service you're using. For sheets, it's here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

Comment: What datatype is auth ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a dart 3rd party library that helps to perform basic operations https://pub.dev/packages/gsheets.

You can also use official library https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis that helps to perform almost any operation, but it's more difficult to use and sometimes requires knowledge of the API https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest