# Flutter - Send email using Google API

Tags: dart, flutter

After much study and repairing the problems, I arrived at the following location that is in my [github](https://github.com/rafaelcb21/gmail_api_flutter). But I do not know if I'm mounting json properly. For the following error is appearing:

```
{
  error: 
    {
      errors: [
        {
          domain: global,
          reason: parseError,
          message: This API does not support parsing form-encoded input.
        }
      ],
      code: 400,
      message: This API does not support parsing form-encoded input.
    }
}
```

I'm setting up the post as follows, for more details the project is in my [github](https://github.com/rafaelcb21/gmail_api_flutter)

```
// scope for send email
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
  ],
);

await googleSignIn.signIn().then((data) {                          
  testingEmail(data.email, data.authHeaders);                          
});


// userId is the email
Future<Null> testingEmail(userId, header) async {
  String url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' + userId + '/messages/send';
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: await header,
    body: {
      'from': userId,
      'to': userId,
      'subject': 'testing send email',
      'text': 'worked!!!'
    }
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong, to not be able to send an email through the Google API? Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: you need to set the Content-Type header to application/json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few changes were made, the main one being that the http post body needed to be a json with the `raw` key and its contents in `base64` And this text that has been converted to base64 must be a MIMEText, so the specific format, as below.

To change the html to text simply change the `Content-Type: text/html` from the string to`Content-Type: text/plain`

The following is a clipping of the code. The complete code is in [github](https://github.com/rafaelcb21/gmail_api_flutter)

```
await googleSignIn.signIn().then((data) {
  data.authHeaders.then((result) {
    var header = {'Authorization': result['Authorization'], 'X-Goog-AuthUser': result['X-Goog-AuthUser']};
    testingEmail(data.email, header);
  });                          
});

Future<Null> testingEmail(String userId, Map header) async {
  header['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  header['Content-type'] = 'application/json';

  var from = userId;
  var to = userId;
  var subject = 'test send email';
  //var message = 'worked!!!';
  var message = "Hi<br/>Html Email";
  var content = '''
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
to: ${to}
from: ${from}
subject: ${subject}

${message}''';

  var bytes = utf8.encode(content);
  var base64 = base64Encode(bytes);
  var body = json.encode({'raw': base64});

  String url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' + userId + '/messages/send';

  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: header,
    body: body
  );
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    setState(() {
      print('error: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
    });
    return;
  }
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
  print('ok: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
}
```

Comment: @rafaelcb21 What should we write in userId, a gmail account name or gmail id for e.g: example@gmail.com ????

Comment: @ArgaPK is account email e.g: myemail@gmail.com