# How to integrate google drive in Flutter app?

Tags: google-drive-api, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a Flutter app, in which I want to integrate my google drive so that I can access contents of my drive through application.

I am a beginner in Flutter and have no prior app development knowledge. Please help me with some code which I can use to perform above mentioned operation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is used to ask for help with your own code. Perhaps you could try asking your question on freelancer.com  for code requests.

Answer (score 11):

The googleapis package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis
provides support for the Drive API.

See [How to use Google API in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898) for how to use it with Flutter GoogleSignIn.