# Flutter GmailApi throws exception Object.noSuchMethod

Tags: dart, flutter, gmail-api

I am trying to create a app which reads messages from Gmail and process them. I was able to achieve that in kotlin using GoogleAccountCredential and Gmail.Build APIs. But I am trying to do the same in Flutter, but no success so far.

I have used https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in to sign in, and then create a HTTPClient similar to one mentioned in this post: [How to use Google API in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter)

Then used that client to create GmailApi : https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/blob/master/generated/googleapis/lib/gmail/v1.dart

Here is the exception I get:

```
E/flutter (21814): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (21814): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'send' was called on null.
E/flutter (21814): Receiver: null
E/flutter (21814): Tried calling: send(Instance of '_RequestImpl')
E/flutter (21814): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (21814): #1      ApiRequester._request.simpleRequest (package:_discoveryapis_commons/src/clients.dart:213:26)
E/flutter (21814): #2      ApiRequester._request (package:_discoveryapis_commons/src/clients.dart:242:25)
E/flutter (21814): #3      ApiRequester.request (package:_discoveryapis_commons/src/clients.dart:66:26)
E/flutter (21814): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21814): #4      UsersMessagesResourceApi.list (package:googleapis/gmail/v1.dart:1540:32)
E/flutter (21814): #5      SignInDemoState._handleGetContact (package:expense_manager/ui/message_homepage.dart:57:69)
E/flutter (21814): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21814): #6      SignInDemoState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:expense_manager/ui/message_homepage.dart:42:9)
E/flutter (21814): #7      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
E/flutter (21814): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
E/flutter (21814): #9      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
E/flutter (21814): #10     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:707:11)
E/flutter (21814): #11     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:667:7)
E/flutter (21814): #12     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (21814): #13     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
I/flutter (21814): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
```

Here is the class:

```
class GoogleHttpClient extends IOClient {
Map<String, String> _headers;

GoogleHttpClient(this._headers) : super();

@override
Future<StreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) =>
    super.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));

@override
Future<Response> head(Object url, {Map<String, String> headers}) =>
    super.head(url, headers: headers..addAll(_headers));
}
```

Invoked like this:

```
_googleSignIn.signIn().then((data) {
  data.authHeaders.then((result) {
    _client = new GoogleHttpClient(result);
  });
});
gmail.GmailApi gmailApi = gmail.GmailApi(_client);
gmail.ListMessagesResponse resp = await gmailApi.users.messages.list(
    'me', q: 'from:bankofamerica');
```

Comment: As mentioned in your error code, seems like the method 'send' was called on null. Please provide the related code in your question, don't expect others to guess what code you used from all those links

Comment: @bunbun, added code in the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Your code handles Dart's `Future` classes incorrectly:

You are trying to access the `_client` variable, but it may not have been initialized yet.

Two ways of handling this:

#### async/await

```
void _signInAsync() async {
  final data = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final result = await data.authHeaders;

  _client = new GoogleHttpClient(result);

  gmail.GmailApi gmailApi = gmail.GmailApi(_client);
  gmail.ListMessagesResponse resp = await gmailApi.users.messages.list(
      'me', q: 'from:bankofamerica');
}
```

#### Future.then

```
void _signInThen() {
  _googleSignIn.signIn().then((data) {
    data.authHeaders.then((result) {
      _client = new GoogleHttpClient(result);
      gmail.GmailApi gmailApi = gmail.GmailApi(_client);
      gmail.ListMessagesResponse resp = await gmailApi.users.messages.list(
          'me', q: 'from:bankofamerica');
    });
  });
}
```

I **highly** recommend reading this page in the Dart documentation: https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, my understanding was little different with async and await. That was the problem. Once i moved gmailApi also inside it started working.