# login & register Flutter Errors

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter but I tried to make an app but I have many problem in the login & register page connect with sqlite I tried many ways I don't know the how to solve it please help regard my problem I appreciate any suggestion in advance.
the error:

```
E/flutter ( 4024): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter ( 4024): #1      _ChangePassPage._submitForm.<anonymous closure>
package:future_uni/…/login/change_pass_page.dart:80
E/flutter ( 4024): #2      State.setState
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1233
E/flutter ( 4024): #3      _ChangePassPage._submitForm
package:future_uni/…/login/change_pass_page.dart:77
E/flutter ( 4024): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:705
E/flutter ( 4024): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:788
E/flutter ( 4024): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
E/flutter ( 4024): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:486
E/flutter ( 4024): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:264
E/flutter ( 4024): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:199
E/flutter ( 4024): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:470
E/flutter ( 4024): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76
E/flutter ( 4024): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117
E/flutter ( 4024): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter ( 4024): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115
E/flutter ( 4024): #15     PointerRouter.route
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101
E/flutter ( 4024): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:218
E/flutter ( 4024): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:198
E/flutter ( 4024): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:156
E/flutter ( 4024): #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:102
E/flutter ( 4024): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:86
E/flutter ( 4024): #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter ( 4024): #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter ( 4024): #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter ( 4024): #24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:274:10)
E/flutter ( 4024): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:183:5)
E/flutter ( 4024):
```

this is the register page to add your password:

```
class ChangePassPage extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChangePassPage();
  }
 }
 class _ChangePassPage extends State<ChangePassPage> {
  
   bool isLoading = false;
   String   _password ;
   int _index;
   LoginResponse _response;
   User user;

   final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   final TextEditingController _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();

 Widget _buildPasswordTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Password', 
          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(
                          ),), ),
      obscureText: true,
      controller: _passwordTextController,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 6) {
          return 'Password invalid';
        }
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _password = value;
      },
    );
  }

Widget _buildPasswordConfirmTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Confirm Password',
          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(
                          ),), ),
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (_passwordTextController.text != value) {
          return 'Password not match';
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void _submitForm() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();

       final form =_formKey.currentState;
       if (form.validate() ) {
         setState(() {
           isLoading= true;
           form.save();
           _response.doregister(user);
           Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
         });
       }
  }
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body:  SingleChildScrollView(
    child:Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),

     child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[ 
       Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
         child:Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:1),
          child: Center(
           child: Card(
            child:Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/Logo_of_future_university_sudan.png',
                height: 130,
                ),
              ],)
            ),),
             decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(
               bottom: BorderSide(color:Color(0xffe46b10)),
               ))
        ),),

        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:60),

          child:Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Form( 
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[ 
                  _title(),
                 SizedBox(height: 40,),

                  _buildPasswordTextField(),
                  
                  SizedBox(height: 40,),

                  _buildPasswordConfirmTextField(),

                  SizedBox(height: 50,),

                  ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,MainModel model) {
                        return model.isLoading
                              ? CircularProgressIndicator
                              :  RaisedButton(
                                  color:Color(0xffe46b10),
                                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                   side: BorderSide(color:Colors.black,width: 2),

                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                   ),
                                   textColor: Colors.black,
                                   child: Text('SUBMIT'),
                                   onPressed: _submitForm
                                   );
                      }
                  )
                ],) ,
                )
            )
          )
          )
        )
              ],)
            )
          )
  );
}
}
```

the Request file:

```
class LoginRequest {
   DatabaseHelper con = new DatabaseHelper();

   Future<User> getLogin(int index , String password ) {
     var result = con.getLogin(index, password);
     return result;
   }

   Future <int> saveUser (User user) async {
     var result = con.saveUser(user);
     return result;
   }
 }
```

the Response file:

```
abstract class LoginCallBack {
   void onLoginSuccess(User user);  
  void onLoginError(String error);  
}

class LoginResponse {
  LoginCallBack _callBack;
  LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
  LoginResponse(this._callBack);

  doLogin(int index, String password) {
    loginRequest.getLogin(index, password)
    .then((user) => _callBack.onLoginSuccess(user))
    .catchError((onError) => _callBack.onLoginError(onError.toString()));
    
  }

  doregister(User user) {
    loginRequest.saveUser(user);
  }
}
```

and Login page:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginPage();
  }
 }
  enum LoginStatus {notSignIn, signIn}

 class _LoginPage extends State<LoginPage> implements LoginCallBack {
  LoginStatus _loginStatus = LoginStatus.notSignIn;
  BuildContext _ctx;

   bool _isLoading = false;
   String   password ;
   int index;
   LoginResponse _response;
  
   final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
   final TextEditingController _indexTextController = TextEditingController();
   final TextEditingController _passTextController = TextEditingController();

_LoginPage(){
  _response= new LoginResponse(this);
}

var value;

getPref() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    value = preferences.getInt("value");
    _loginStatus = value == 1 ? LoginStatus.signIn : LoginStatus.notSignIn;
    
  });
}

signOut() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    preferences.setInt("value", null);
    _loginStatus = LoginStatus.notSignIn;
  });
}
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getPref();
}

Widget _buildIndexTextField() {
    var textFormField = TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Index Number', 
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(
                              ),), ),
                              
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: _indexTextController,
          validator: (String value) {
            if (value.isEmpty || value.length > 11) {
              return 'Please enter a valid index';
            }
          },
          onSaved: (value) => index = num.tryParse(value) 
        );
        return textFormField;
  }

  Widget _buildPasswordTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Password', 
           border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(
                          ),), ),
      obscureText: true,
      controller: _passTextController,

      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 6) {
          return 'Password invalid';
        }
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        password = value;
      },
    );
  }


void _submitForm() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();

   
       final form =_formKey.currentState;
       if (form.validate() && _indexTextController.text != _passTextController.text ) {
         setState(() {
           _isLoading= true;
           form.save();
           _response.doLogin(index, password);
           Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
         });
       }
       if (form.validate() && _indexTextController.text == _passTextController.text) {
         setState(() {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/passconfirm');

         });
       };
      }
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  switch (_loginStatus) {
    case LoginStatus.notSignIn:
    _ctx = context;
      var loginForm = new 
          SingleChildScrollView(
    child:Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[ 

        Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
         child:Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:1),
          child: Center(
           child: Card(
            child:Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/Logo_of_future_university_sudan.png',
                height: 130,
                ),
              ],)
            ),),
             decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(
               bottom: BorderSide( color:Color(0xffe46b10)),
               ))
        ),),

        Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:30),
             child:Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Form( 
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[ 
                  _title(),

                   SizedBox(height: 50,),

                  _buildIndexTextField(),

                  SizedBox(height: 30,),

                  _buildPasswordTextField(),
                  
                  SizedBox(height: 80,),
            
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 180.0),
              child: ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,MainModel model) {
                        return model.isLoading
                              ? CircularProgressIndicator
                              :  RaisedButton(
                                color:Color(0xffe46b10),
                                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  side: BorderSide(color:Colors.black,width: 2),
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                   ),
                                   textColor: Colors.black,
                                   child: Text('LOGIN'),
                                   onPressed: _submitForm
                                   );
                      }
                  )
                )
                ],) ,
                )
            )
          )
          )
        ]),
        
        )
    );

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
        child: loginForm,
      ),);
      break;
      case LoginStatus.signIn:
      return HomePage(signOut());
      break;
    
  }
 }

savePref(int value,int index, String password) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    preferences.setInt("value", value);
    preferences.setInt("index", index);
    preferences.setString("password", password);
    
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884353/flutter-gmailapi-throws-exception-object-nosuchmethod You can have a read about this. This might help to solve your error and more things, try to debug your code little by little. print something on console to see when your program crash or stopped working. It helps :D Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You never implement `onLoginSuccess` or `onLoginError` in `_LoginPage`.

Comment: i already implement it and receive this error  *Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near "index": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Users (
            index INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, password  TEXT
          ))) *