# How to get Client parameter for google_api from firebase auth

Tags: dart, flutter

```
 Client client1 = clientViaApiKey(apikey);

    var api = new youtube.YoutubeApi(client1);
```

I used the googleapis auth package but it is showing error

```
DetailedApiRequestError(status: 401, message: Login Required)
```

Comment: What Google API are you talking about? What package are you using for that?

Comment: You might be able to use https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.youtube.v3/googleapis.youtube.v3-library.html with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks that worked for me