# Flutter Google Drive Integration

Tags: google-drive-api, flutter

I've been learning flutter for few days now and I wanted to make an app that uses google drive integration. I couldn't find a way to make it work.

Comment: You could try checking Google Drive API

Comment: I did look into it but I am confused on how I use the API.

Comment: Then instead you should learn about how to make calls to API and explore what can you do with that

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898

Comment: It has been a while. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

check [this package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis). You can use this package and look for [API endpoints](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/) from official Google APIs.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using this package, the place where I got stuck is how do I get the AuthClient for google drive after use login. I am kinda confused with this.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to immediately integrate something with Google Drive, because from November 2019 Google wants to abandon the possibility of using some of the primordial features of Google Drive API;