# Error: Not found: 'dart:html' when using googleapis_auth dart team package with flutter

Tags: google-api, dart, flutter

When using

- [googleapis_auth | Dart Package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis_auth#-readme-tab-)
- [googleapis | Dart Package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis#-readme-tab-)

to access Google Api's thru Flutter using this code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_browser.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/androidpublisher/v3.dart';

Future main() async {
  dynamic jsonData = json.decode(
      await File('api-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json')
          .readAsString());
  var scopes = [AndroidpublisherApi.AndroidpublisherScope];
  final accountCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(jsonData);

  AuthClient client = await clientViaServiceAccount(accountCredentials, scopes);


}
```

you will get this error

> Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html' as html;

Comment: You might be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Base on [FAQ - Flutter](https://flutter.io/docs/resources/faq#can-flutter-run-any-dart-code) :

> #### Can Flutter run any Dart code?
>
> Flutter should be able to run most Dart code that does not import (transitively, or directly) dart:mirrors or dart:html.

---

### Problem synonym and analysis :

- Look like you are using a package
- which depends on 'dart:html'
- which is not supported in Flutter

### Solution :

- remove

  ```
  import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_browser.dart';
  ```