# flutter dart error when installing google api calendar

Tags: dart, flutter

I will display a list of events from Google Calendar.
I followed the example already in the following link : [How to use Google API in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898)

and my script is as follows :

`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

assumed I was logged in.

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
  ],
);'
```

```
class GoogleHttpClient extends http.BaseClient {
  Map<String, String> _headers;

  GoogleHttpClient(this._headers) : super();

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) =>
      super.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers)); //have error 'the method 'send' is always abstract in the supertype'

  @override
  Future<http.Response> head(Object url, {Map<String, String> headers}) =>
      super.head(url, headers: headers..addAll(_headers));
}
```

```
void getCalendarEvents() async {
    final authHeaders = _googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders;
    final httpClient = new GoogleHttpClient(authHeaders); //have error "The argument type 'Future<Map<String, String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, String>'"
    var calendar = new Calendar.CalendarApi(new http.Client());
    var calEvents = calendar.events.list("primary");
    calEvents.then((Calendar.Events events) {
      events.items.forEach((Calendar.Event event) {print(event.summary);});
    });
}
```

the above script cannot run because of an error.

> the method 'send' is always abstract in the supertype

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is based on [How to use Google API in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898) you'll see that I have a `@override Future<StreamedResponse> send(...)` in my code.

`GoogleHttpClient` extends `abstract class IOClient` that is missing an implementation of `send`, so the concrete subclass needs to implement it.

That's what the error message is about.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer.
how do I implement abstract class `IOClient` itself?

I just define it as follows :
`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`
thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment. Please check the code in the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898

Answer (score 1):

Replace StreamedResponse with IOStreamedResponse
add IOClient library
replace `class GoogleHttpClient extends IOClient` with `class GoogleHttpClient extends http.BaseClient`

Answer (score 0):

1 This is error

```
//have error "The argument type 'Future<Map<String, String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, String>'"
```

**fixed**: add ***await*** ahead

Like below:

```
final authHeaders = await _googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders;
```

2: Change like below

```
var calendar = new Calendar.CalendarApi(new http.Client());
```

to

```
var calendar = new Calendar.CalendarApi(httpClient);
```

======> Final:

```
void getCalendarEvents() async {
final authHeaders = await _googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders;
final httpClient = new GoogleHttpClient(authHeaders);
var calendar = new Calendar.CalendarApi(httpClient);
var calEvents = calendar.events.list("primary");
calEvents.then((Calendar.Events events) {
  events.items.forEach((Calendar.Event event) {print(event.summary);});
});
}
```

It worked for me.