# How to integrate google calendar api with flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate google calendar api into my flutter app but i can't find any proper guide to do this so my question is how can i integrate google calendar api in my flutter app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898 might help

Comment: Take a look at this article https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-use-google-calendar-api-adding-the-events-to-calendar-3d8fcb008493

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good guide that you can follow posted on [Medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-use-google-calendar-api-adding-the-events-to-calendar-3d8fcb008493). You'd need to at least use [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) and [googleapis_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth) plugin to get started.