# Is it possible to Flutter apps to write on iCloud/Google drive?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and am trying to figure out if there is a way in  flutter to write a file to iCloud (iOS) or google drive (Android). There seem to be APIs to do this in Swift/Android native dev, but I can't find anything in a flutter.

I essentially want my app to write on a text file in iCloud so that another install of the same app on a different phone by the same user can access that file. I'm trying to do this without my own cloud setup (no firebase etc, since it's so simple and small), so I thought iCloud/gDrive would be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

The [icloud_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/icloud_storage) package does upload and download with iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

The [googleapis](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis) package provides rudimentary support for the Drive API. You'd want to use the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) for authentication as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter/48485898#48485898).

I looked into it a while back but didn't continue due to how young it looked.

I've got no experience with iCloud so I can't really help you there, but I think you'd need to write your own platform plugin or use an HTTP API, if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm late to the party but there is this module
https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker
I haven't used it myself but they seem to support iCloud