# Getting 'String is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' error when calling clientViaServiceAccount

Tags: google-sheets, dart, flutter, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to add a user's first name and last name to cells A and B to the target google sheet but I keep getting the error :

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type
>   'String' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

whenever I submit my code.

I know that the error is isolated to the **clientViaServiceAccount** block of code because that's the line of code that the error stack points to. I've tried changing _scopes to `[SheetsApi.SpreadsheetsScope]` in the parameters but that led to the same thing.

I modeled this block of code based off of the example here:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis#-example-tab-
and the second answer here:
[Google Sheets API v4 for Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466410/google-sheets-api-v4-for-flutter-dart/46466452#46466452)

```
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()){
  Navigator.push(
    context, 
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConfirmationPage()),
  );
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  final _privateKey = { 'private JSON key' };
  final _cred = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(_privateKey);
  final _scopes = [SheetsApi.SpreadsheetsScope];
  Map<String,String> _sheets = {
    "ISMI": 'sheet key',
    "NORCO": 'sheet key 2'
  };
  clientViaServiceAccount(_cred, _scopes).then((client){
    var api = new SheetsApi(client);
    ValueRange vr = new ValueRange.fromJson({"values": [_newUser.firstName,_newUser.lastName]});
    api.spreadsheets.values.append(vr,_sheets[_newUser.location],'A:B').then((AppendValuesResponse r) {
      client.close();
    });
  });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the JSON needs to be surrounded by r''''''. So I changed the _privateKey variable to this:

```
final _privateKey = r'''{private JSON key}''';
```