# Reading from Google Sheet in Flutter / Dart

Tags: google-sheets, flutter, dart, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to read and write data to google sheets in a Flutter application, but I can't figure out how to. I have not been able to find any documentation or examples for this issue. I am also fairly new to both Flutter / Dart and the Google API so I do not really know what I am doing.

Any help would be massively appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: You are using google sheets V4? 
Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46466452/1785285) answer will help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets API v4 for Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466410/google-sheets-api-v4-for-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can read spreadhseets from Google Sheets using [`googleapis`](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) package. Note that this requires the use of [`googleapis_auth`](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth) package for authentication.

```dart
Future readSpreadSheet() async {
  final httpClient = await clientViaApplicationDefaultCredentials(scopes: [
    StorageApi.devstorageReadOnlyScope,
  ]);
  try {
    final spreadsheetApi = SheetsApi(httpClient);
    spreadsheetApi.spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId).then((Spreadsheet spreadsheet) {
      // Handle Spreadsheet
      // https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/sheets.v4/Spreadsheet-class.html
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint('$error: $stackTrace');
    });
  } finally {
      httpClient.close();
  }
}
```

For fetching the `spreadsheetId`, you'll be needing to use [`drive.v3`](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/drive.v3/drive.v3-library.html) API from `googleapis` package.